# R.java missing but no xml errors

Tags: android, resources, r.java-file

I have been trying to convert my activities into fragments, and during the process somewhere I messed something up in one of my files. I am getting the error where it can't find my R.java file, and I checked all of my libraries but there are no errors in their xml files. Nor are there errors in my apps xml files. Well, there might be, but they aren't showing up.

I have cleaned my projects multiple times, and I have restarted Eclipse, but nothing seems to work. No errors are coming up in my xml files, so do you all have any ideas for fixing this?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fotolife.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_retina"
        android:label="The Foto Life"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fotolife.app.LOGIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainView"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fotolife.app.MAINVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fotolife.app.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Upload"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fotolife.app.UPLOAD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fotolife.app.MAPS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidCustomGalleryActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fotolife.app.GALLERY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditGallery"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fotolife.app.GALLERY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UploadQueue"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FeatherDefaultTheme.Custom" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.receivers.FeatherSystemReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":feather_system_receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.library.providers.FeatherContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.fotolife.app.upload"
            android:exported="false" >
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
            android:value="a150e7b057ac915" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have a  tag in my manifest that I move around and don't get errors. Can you tell me the correct location for it?

Comment: Can you post your manifest? Make sure you have entered the right package name.

Comment: I posted it and checked. It is right.

Comment: what happens when you try to compile the application, try to compile the application, sometimes it happens to me that Eclipse doesn't make R.Java when I clean it but it gets created when I compile.

Comment: See the problem `tab` in `eclipse` for further details.

Comment: You've got several references in your manifest, eg android:icon, android:label, android:theme. Check that these are all valid. These errors dont showup red in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Update the Build Tools in Android SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

Delete your 'gen' and 'bin' folder, then check the 'Problem' Tab (in eclipse).  I bet you are missing an XML reference, or have another error in an XML file (sometimes not escaping slashes or quotes can do it).

Finally, check your project properties to make sure you are still targeting the appropriate SDK Version, and that your libraries are all still linked.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. There was an 8 hiding in my edit.xml file..... I got rid of it and the problem was fixed.